# Verify image/logo presence in a web failed using selenium java

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver

I am new to Selenium. In this case, I want to verify image/logo in this guru99 webpage for my own enablement. I already tried to find element using xpath but the output said no images shown. Is there any method to verify this image other than find element? Kindly refer below inspect:

[image: inspect image element]

Here's the code (please see after "verify image" comment:

```
@Test
        public void testParameterWithXML() throws InterruptedException, AWTException{
            driver.get("http://demo.guru99.com/V4/");
            //Find user name
            WebElement userName = driver.findElement(By.name("uid"));
            //Fill user name
            userName.sendKeys("guru99");
            //Find password
            WebElement password = driver.findElement(By.name("password"));
            //Fill password
            password.sendKeys("guru99");
            //Press enter
            //driver.findElement(By.name("btnLogin")).click();
            
            //add verification -img, texts
            
            //verify title
            Boolean verifyTitle = driver.getTitle().equalsIgnoreCase("Guru99 Bank Home Page");
            System.out.println(verifyTitle);
            assertTrue(verifyTitle);
            
            //verify text demo site
            //WebElement demosite = driver.findElement(By.className("site-name"));
            //System.out.println(demosite);
            
            //verify image
            WebElement ImageFile = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/a/img"));
            Boolean ImagePresent = (Boolean) ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].complete && typeof arguments[0].naturalWidth != \"undefined\" && arguments[0].naturalWidth > 0", ImageFile);
    
            if (!ImagePresent)
            {
            System.out.println("Image displayed.");
            }
            else
            {
            System.out.println("Image not displayed.");
            }
            
            
        }
```

This is the result. FYI i run my test with cross browser testing, which I run all the tests in 3 browsers at one time. Hence, test run = 3. The true is for verify title (not an issue here), but for images it is considered failed because it unable to verify the images present:

[image: testng result]